# Вложенность в дочерних элементах

Tags: jquery

Как добавить класс к каждому второму элементу th в каждом элементе tr?

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><th>
        <th><th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><th>
        <th><th>       
    </tr>
</tbody>
$(".highlited tbody:nth-child(1) tr th:nth-child(2) ").addClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не закрыт тэг `<th>`, ваш код отлично работает и каждому второму th добавляет класс hidden

```
<table class="highlited">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="hidden"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="hidden"></th>       
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```